# ShareLinkContent on facebook in android

Tags: android-facebook

I encountered 1 problem.

Hope everybody help please.

1. I have 1 android application using Facebook sdk. Recently Facebook reported that the app violates policy 4.a, (as attached image), So what should I do next to fix this error?

[image]

2. I can't share to facebook using ShareContent, because the dialog appears and then disappears immediately. I received the following error message:

> com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100,
> subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage:
> Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17837578*******' does not
> exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not
> support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at
> [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%7D)

Following the path in the Bug log, I use the following function:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
accessToken,
  new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
      // Insert your code here
    }
});

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

So what is the

> accessToken

here, how to create it?

Thank you everyone for reading.

Comment: These look like two distinct problems. The first one is quite clear: in order to comply you need to write a Privacy Policy, host this on a publicly available website and link to this policy from your app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.